# CosmosDb: Channel is closed

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

My production code has been running for several month with no problem using CosmosDB, now however I've got several logs with this message.

Could somebody help me understand the nature of this or perhaps point somewhere where I can read up on this?

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: Channel is closed
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ClientExtensions.<ParseResponseAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<>c__DisplayClass10.<<InvokeAsync>b__f>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__1b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<InvokeAsync>d__1f.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__328.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteQueryRequestInternalAsync>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteQueryRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__e.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
```

Comment: Are you using Tcp connection?

Comment: no it's communicating through https with azure API

Comment: Did you by any change meet the 10GB maximum storage limit?

Comment: For sure not. Everything is working fine now, just had this error with "Channel is closed" and nothing else. It seems like the default retry policy has tried and threw this, but what does "channel is closed?" means exactly? To what I said previously that it's https, I see that we use the default DocumentClient without settings the ConnectionPolicy.

Comment: It will still default to the default connection policy which internally will set the request timeout to 60 seconds and then the retry logic to be 9 maximum attempts in throttled requests and 30 seconds max retry wait time.